# Do I need to use prepared statements when selecting values from DB which was inserted by an user

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, mysqli

Do I need to use prepared statements when selecting values from MYSQL which was previously inserted by an user via prepared statement?

I'm talking about PHP / MYSQL(i)

Comment: No, but why "mix and match".... it's easier and cleaner always to use prepared statements/bind variables, and if you get into that habit you'll not forget it when you do need it

Comment: No, you don't **need** to. You **should** use them. They are making your life easier after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the statement is just `select foo1, foo2 from tbl`, then no, but if you have conditions to filter it, it can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make a selective selection you will have to use prepared statements with WHERE parameters in SQL statement